# There are many buttons, when click on one of them, how to change its label?

Tags: apache-flex, events, onclick

I'm writing a very simple flex application with mxml. I have many buttons, when I click one of them, I hope its value changes to `World`.

My code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Declarations>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private function hello():void {
                this.label = "World!";
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:HBox>
        <s:Button click="hello()" label="Hello" />
        <s:Button click="hello()" label="Hello" />
        <s:Button click="hello()" label="Hello" />
        <s:Button click="hello()" label="Hello" />
        <s:Button click="hello()" label="Hello" />
    </mx:HBox>

</s:Application>
```

Which is incorrect since `this.label = "World!"` can't be compiled that `this.label` is not found.

How to let the `this` reference to the button I clicked, or how to implement this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code this may help you: -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Declarations>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private function hello(event:MouseEvent):void {
                event.currentTarget.label = "World!";
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:HBox>
        <s:Button click="hello(event)" label="Hello" />
        <s:Button click="hello(event)" label="Hello" />
        <s:Button click="hello(event)" label="Hello" />
        <s:Button click="hello(event)" label="Hello" />
        <s:Button click="hello(event)" label="Hello" />
    </mx:HBox>

</s:Application>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. And I wonder if "event" is the only way? Is there a way to bind the `this` of "hello" function to a button?

Comment: No, this is not the way it works in flex, otherwise add a parameter to the hello() function that reflects the current button `click="hello(event, this)"` but it seems useless does not it?

Comment: Just to clarify, calling `this` in your application would refer to the `Application`, not the button.